# React anchor tag won't take me to another component on the same page

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a webpage using React that has multiple components all on the same page. On the header, there are list items with anchor tags that have an href pointing to the ID of another component. When I click on the link, nothing happens on the web page. When I put an anchor tag pointing to the header item, it works. I'm guessing because the link and the reference is in the same component. How do I fix this?

HTML (Inside the header component)

```
<li><a className="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
```

The about link would not work. If I were to put an anchor with the href to "#header", it would work.

React Components

```
      <Header />
      <Intro/>
      <About />
      <Schedule />
```

Thank you very much for the help. This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow so it is nice to meet you guys.

Comment: The anchor is looking for an HTML element, not a React component.

Comment: In my other React Components, there are section tags with the corresponding ID to the anchor tags in the header. So there are matching HTML elements, I'm just not sure why it won't lead to it.